# Can't get a basic toggleClass to work

Tags: jquery

I've been trying at this for a while, and I just don't know why this simple toggleClass won't work.  When I am doing an element inspection in my dev tools, I see my element flicker as if it is trying to do something.  Not getting a single console error.  It will let me addClass no problem, but when I switch to toggleClass it doesn't work.

My code is:

```
<div class="header-top-wrap">
    <a class="nav-opener"></a>
</div>

$(".nav-opener").on("click",function() {
    $(".header-top-wrap").toggleClass("nav-active");
});
```

Comment: `I see my element flicker` is usually an indication you are attaching the click event twice to the element.

Comment: So where would I be attaching it again at? That is the only line of code for it.

Comment: I changed the toggleClass to a few random things to make sure it wasn't being called twice, and it isn't.

Comment: It seemed an external javascript source was conflicting with my javascript.  So that was the main issue.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having all of your code, this is tough to debug. Here is an example jsFiddle that uses your exact JS and is working: the text color changes `onclick`: https://jsfiddle.net/qk5ue9yv/

```js
$(".nav-opener").on("click",function() {
    $(".header-top-wrap").toggleClass("nav-active");
});
```

```css
.nav-active{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-opener">
  <div class="header-top-wrap">
    hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think I had the code wrong.  I will have to see if there is any outside js sources messing with it.  I deleted all the js I created besides this one toggle, and it still doesn't work.  So it may be some outside js that I'm pulling in that is conflicting with it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".nav-opener").click(function(){

     $(".header-top-wrap").toggleClass("nav-active");
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!